# Converting Json to Csv format in android app

Tags: java, android, csv

Iam converting Json file to Csv format in android application and downloading it in phone storage.Iam doing it all on a button click.Right now its creating the .csv file in phone storage but the file is null.I have debugged the application its getting strings from json in for loop but dont kno why its not writting it in csv file.The .csv file created in phone storage is always null.
Also I want to give headings to each row how can I do that.

here is my function in whihc Iam writing csv:

```
public void saveCsv(JSONArray outerArray) throws IOException, JSONException {
        String rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/test/";
        File dir = new File(rootPath);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        File file = null;
        file = new File(rootPath, "test4.csv");
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        if (file.exists()) {
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file), ',');
            for (int i = 0; i < outerArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONArray innerJsonArray =  (JSONArray) outerArray.getJSONArray(i);
                for(int k=0; k<innerJsonArray.length(); k++)
                {
                    String[][] arrayOfArrays = new String[innerJsonArray.length()][];
                    JSONObject innerJsonObject=  (JSONObject) innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(k);
                    String[] stringArray1 = new String[innerJsonObject.length()];

                    stringArray1[0]= (String) innerJsonObject.getString("type");
                    stringArray1[1]= (String) innerJsonObject.getString("title");
                    stringArray1[2]="";
                    JSONArray jsonArray= (JSONArray) innerJsonObject.getJSONArray("answer");
                    for (int j=0; j<jsonArray.length(); j++)
                    {
                        stringArray1[2]+=jsonArray.get(j).toString();
                        stringArray1[2]+=",";
                    }

                    arrayOfArrays[k] = stringArray1;
                    writer.writeNext(arrayOfArrays[k]);
                }
            }
            writer.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: post your JSONArray here

Comment: Iam creating json at run time from firebase database

Comment: any dummy format

Comment: [[{"answer":["2"],"type":1,"title":"Ques2 radiio"},{"answer":["0","1","3"],"type":3,"title":"Ques3 chk"},{"answer":["Simple text"],"type":2,"title":"Ques1 text"},{"answer":["Essay writing "],"type":4,"title":"Ques4 para"}]]

Comment: its working for me,you didn't have a storage permission may be

Comment: ok.Can you tell me how to give the headings to rows in csv file

Comment: add extra object like this for heading {
"answer":[
"2"
],
"type":1,
"title":"Ques2 radiio"
}

Comment: Wont it repeat the heading again and again,I want it only One time like Questions and Answers.
can you show me in code where should I do that

Comment: You just need to add it once in the beginning before the loop.

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk Iam doing this but its not giving headings
  for (int k = 0; k < innerJsonArray.length(); k++) {
                    String[][] arrayOfArrays = new String[innerJsonArray.length()][];
                    JSONObject innerJsonObject = (JSONObject) innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(k);
                    String[] stringArray1 = new String[innerJsonObject.length()];
                    stringArray1[1] = "Questions";
        stringArray1[2] = "Answers";
                    stringArray1[1] = (String) innerJsonObject.getString("title");
                    stringArray1[2] = " "

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONArray innerJsonArray =  (JSONArray) outerArray.getJSONArray(i);
```

You change Like

```
 JSONObject innerJsonArray =  (JSONObject) outerArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

update this function

```
    public void saveCsv(JSONArray outerArray) throws IOException, JSONException {

        String rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/test/";
        File dir = new File(rootPath);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        File file = null;
        file = new File(rootPath, "test4.csv");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        int a = 0;
        if (file.exists()) {
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file), ',');
            for (int i = 0; i < outerArray.length()-1; i++) {
                JSONObject innerJsonArray = (JSONObject) outerArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String[] arrayOfArrays = new String[innerJsonArray.length()];
                String[] stringArray1 = new String[innerJsonArray.length()];

                stringArray1[0] =  innerJsonArray.getString("type");
                stringArray1[1] =  innerJsonArray.getString("title");
                stringArray1[2] = "";
                JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) innerJsonArray.getJSONArray("answer");
                for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                    stringArray1[2] += jsonArray.get(j).toString();
                    stringArray1[2] += ",";
                }

                arrayOfArrays = stringArray1;
                a++;
                writer.writeNext(arrayOfArrays);

            }
            writer.close();
        }
    }
```

it will be work

[image]